# Joining a DataFrame on itself to speed up iteration

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I am working on a data project and I'm trying to speed up my initial data processing because inevitably I want to do something else/new with the data. So far I've been trying to do more vectorization and using np.where and the like. I've seen material gains with just that.

The last bit of my code that I need to process is the slowest. I am using itterrows to cycle through a very large dataframe (>million rows).

What I am essentially trying to do is the SQL equivalent of

```
select curr.value, prev.value from t1 left join t2 on curr.number = prev.number - 1
```

As far as I know, there's no way to join a DataFrame on itself like that. Is there some other way to iterate through it to compare the current and previous values? Here's how the data frame currently looks

```
df = 
[a b c
 3 1 0
 4 1 0
 5 1 0
 6 0 1]
```

Note that b goes from 1 to 0 and that's what I am trying to capture such that I would now have a df that looks like this

```
[a b c b_c
 3 1 0  0
 4 1 0  0
 5 1 0  0
 6 0 1  1]
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: so `1-df['b']` ? sorry if i didnt get you can you explain a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this. Basically you want to know the switch from b to c and back.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["a"] = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
df["b"] = [1,1,1,0,0,1,1]
df["c"] = [0,0,0,1,1,0,0]

df["b_c"] = df["b"].eq(df["c"].shift()).astype(int)

print(df)
```

## Output:

```
   a  b  c  b_c
0  3  1  0    0
1  4  1  0    0
2  5  1  0    0
3  6  0  1    1
4  7  0  1    0
5  8  1  0    1
6  9  1  0    0
```

I'm not sure if this is the fastest method out there or if it's faster than with iterrows but I assume it is. (at least it looks nice)

Comment: Boendal, thanks, that's the method I've been looking for. Appreciate it